# How to customize UI Dialogs in Wix to modify location/size of Labels

Tags: user-interface, wix

I've been wanting to modify the location of the `InstallDirDlgDescription` text (Click Next to install to the default folder or click Change to choose another.)
The x co-ordinate of this text by default is X="25" and the text overlaps with my logo (I've customized the dialog to change the banner to my logo).

I know I can change the VALUE of the String by doing -->

```
<String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription">This is a custom message.</String>
```

But is there a way of changing the location of the text (I want to set X = "5" so that the text shifts to left and doesn't overlap with my logo) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`UI`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wixloc/ui.html) element to change control attributes. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/ for examples.