# How can I change the width of the Textbox in the header?

Tags: wix, wix3, windows-installer, wix3.8

We are using Wix Toolset 3.11 to build an .msi. We use a banner that contains our company logo:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Banner.bmp"/>
```

**The Problem:** Our logo has a width of 130px. In some Dialogs, the text in the header is too long and collides with the Logo:

[image]

**Question**: How can we limit the width of the textbox in the header so that the text will break into the next line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize UI Dialogs in Wix to modify location/size of Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495164/how-to-customize-ui-dialogs-in-wix-to-modify-location-size-of-labels)

Comment: @dvorn: Thank your very much for your help. But I think this is no duplicate. Your linked post discusses the topic too general and my question is more special. E.g. I cannot find there which UI-Dialog Element to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .wxl File add an UI-Element and set the width of the `Description` control for a dialog:

```
<WixLocalization>
    [...]
    <UI Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Description" Width="whatever, default 280"/>
</WixLocalization>
```

Instead of the `Description` control you also can change the width of the `Title` control.

[How to customize UI Dialogs in Wix to modify location/size of Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495164/how-to-customize-ui-dialogs-in-wix-to-modify-location-size-of-labels)

If you want your text to wrap in the control, be sure to set also the Height attribute large enough.  E.g. to double the height of the above control, set Height="30".

Comment: This is not correct. The UI element does not contain the properties 'Diealog', 'Control' or 'Width' as you can see in the documentation: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/ui.html

Comment: @Simon This is wxl file, its schema here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wixloc/

Comment: A good answer. when I use this UI in the .wxl file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization" Culture="en-us" Codepage='1252'>
 [...]
  <UI Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Description" Width="50" />
</WixLocalization>`

Then the Text will be cut and three dots appended: 'Click nex...'. I want to reward you with an vote-up. I wait for someone who can tell me a solution, that puts the text in a new line (Like InnoSetup it does).

Comment: Perhaps another question: How can I apply the Width to all dialogs. Not only the InstallDirDlg?

Comment: @Simon The control should have NoWrap="No" attribute.  I thought that is the default...

Comment: @Simon You cannot apply Width to all dialogs.  They are defined individually, see https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib

Comment: @Simon Yes, NoWrap=No is the default, but that particular control is not high enough to include another line of text.  I updated the answer.

Comment: The text now wraps into a new line when I set the height attribute to the value 20. Thank you very much.